# checking number range using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check and validate certain numbers on ranges eg (1 to 6) using Javascript.
I have tried solutions one and two but cannot get it to work.

**solution 1**

```
var num =9;
if (!in_array(num, 1,6)){
    alert('this number is not within the range);
}
```

**solution 2**

```
var num =9;
if (num =>1 && num <=6){
    alert('this number is okay);
} else{
    alert('this number is not within the range);
}
```

Comment: `=>` is not a valid comparison operator, you want `>=` (`=>` is a lambda function operator)

Comment: Solution 1 doesn't work because you're not using an array, and `in_array` is not a native method, so unless it's something you've defined, we can't see it

Comment: "*cannot get it work*" is not a problem description. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

num>= not num=>

```
 var num =9;
        if (num >=1 && num <=6){
        alert('this number is okay');
        } else{
    alert('this number is not within the range');
    }
```